# Branch “users/<username>” organization for git repos in visual studio team services

Tags: branch, git-branch, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've seen this question on another forum with no answers and I am actually trying to figure out the same thing.

https://superuser.com/questions/1120229/vsts-branch-users-username-organization-for-git-repos

Any idea how to create a branch under users//?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `users/frank` as a branch. But you can't then create `users/frank/somefeature`. Just create the branch locally with the full name `users/frank` and then publish it to VSTS from Visual Studio or push from the commandline.

Comment: Thanks! I just realised that I was using the wrong '\' character. It worked like a charm now!